# Writing a thesis: how to organize the content?

Tags: thesis, writing-style

I have to start writing a thesis for my master's degree. The thesis itself is about machine learning. In particular, I developed an environment that simulate a real world robotic system and applied some of the most famous reinforcement learning algorithms to it. I would like to receive some tips on how to organize it in an effective way.

Right now, my idea is to organize it in the following sections:

- **Abstract** - Briefly introduce the topic of the thesis explaining what will be covered next.
- **State of the art** - Introduction to the topic of machine learning, in particular reinforcement learning (how much in detail should I go since there is a section dedicated to the agents?)
- **Tools** - A list of all the tools used. Basically the simulator and some machine learning libraries.
- **Simulation** - Explain in details how the simulation works. That is, how the robotic system physically works.
- **Environment** - Explain  the environment is structured. That is, how the robotic system is controlled. (should this be merged with "Simulation"?)
- **Agents** - Explain how the different RL algorithms work in detail.
- **Results** - A lot of plots and tables and some explanations regarding the results of the training of the different algorithms.
- **Conclusion** - What I've done, what I've not, what could be done better in the future.

---

This question could be opinion based but exist some common rules when writing a thesis of which I'm not fully aware. I'm more interested in the latter but of course, if you want to share your opinion it will be welcomed.

Comment: Every person's thesis in different fields will be different. At first glance, this seems like an okay organization. I suggest talking to your university's writing center (or similarly named thing) - the people there are trained to help you in the writing process.

Comment: To add to the comment of @SeanRoberson, or just go to the university library and look through a few recent theses from your institution. You can also run your outline past your advisor, which is probably the smartest thing to do.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I'll do as soon as possible.

Comment: Look at how other theses in the field are organized, how your advisor’s previous students’ theses are organized, and ask your advisor for recommendations.